# Класс в Java или основы

Tags: java, классы

Учусь работать с классами в Java, как создать класс "Автомобиль", в котором есть разные марки автомобилей и чтобы можно было к примеру вывести все машины с красным цветом.

Как сделал это я:

```
public class Auto {
   String Name;
   String Color;
   int Speed;
   int Size;

  void BMW(){
       Color= "Red";
   }
   //и там далее
```

Но так нельзя обратиться к BMW и узнать какой у нее color, а у меня получаться только обратиться полностью к `BMW()`, но не к `BMW.COLOR`.

Comment: Сами поняли что написали?)

Comment: `Auto BMW = new Auto(); 
BMW.color;`

Comment: Вам нужно создавать объекты (экземпляры классов), чтобы получить конкретные модели автомобилей, а не писать методы моделей автомобилей в классе - в методах вы пишите ДЕЙСТВИЯ, которые мог бы выполнять каждый из автомобилей (экземпляров класса) - ехать, моргать фарами и тд.

Comment: Еще возможный вариант - это создать класс auto и потом создавать классы с марками машин , которые расширяют класс auto. получится примерно так public class Bmw extends Auto () { ... }. Таким образом класс Bmw будет обладать всеми полями и методами класса Auto и так же можно создавать доп.возвожности для Bmw в её классе.

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего тебе надо создать конструктор для класса автомобиля и передавать туда цвет и марку машины:

```
public Auto(String color, String name) {
  this.color = color;
  this.name = name;
}
```

Переменные лучше именовать в нижнем регистре.

Answer (score 2):

В этом случае эти методы называют обычно геттер и сеттер, чтобы использовать в общей модели.

Переменные классов принято именовать с маленькой буквы, классы с большой.
Вот пример как можно сделать BMW.

```
public class Auto {
    private String _name;
    private String _color;

    public Auto(String name, String color) {
        _color = color;
        _name = name;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return _color;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return _name;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        _color = color;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        _name = name;
    }
}
```

И уже в самой программе ты можешь создать БМВ

```
Auto blackBumer = new Auto("BMW", "Black");
```